# Session variables seem to be dissapearing when i go to a user profile

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a search function where it finds users where after I can click on a name and it brings me to their profile.

The search part works and I get back a list of clickable names.

The problem starts when I click on the name and go to the user-profile page.
It will always end up on the last result of my search query ( so let's say i type in 'R' and I get the results:

rik
richard
roland

it will always go to Rolands profile no matter what i click

Keep in mind, in the URL it does appear to have the right 'idUsers'

Here is the relevant code:

**search-student.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <?php  session_start(); ?>
<title>Student zoeken</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search">
 </form>
 <?php

 $idUser;
 $fname;
 $lname;
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$key=$_POST["search"];  //key=pattern to be searched
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sbsdb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where `f_name` like '%$key%'"); 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$_SESSION['idUsers'] = $row['idUsers'];
$_SESSION['f_name'] = $row['f_name'];
$_SESSION['l_name'] = $row['l_name'];
$_SESSION['imgUsers'] = $row['userImg'];
echo '<br><a href="user-profile.php?id='.$row['idUsers'].'">'.$row['f_name'].' '.$row['l_name']. '</a>';
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**user-profile.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    define('TITLE',"user Profile");
    include 'includes/userProfileHeader.php';
?>

<h3><?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['f_name']) . ' ' . strtoupper($_SESSION['l_name']); ?></h3>                
<p>
    <?php 
        if ($_SESSION['gender'] == 'm')
        {
            echo 'Male';
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['gender'] == 'f')
        {
            echo 'Female';
        }
    ?>
</p>
<h6><?php echo $_SESSION['headline']; ?></h6>
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['bio'];?></p> 
<br><br><br><br>     
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

** userProfileHeader **

```
<?php
require 'dbh.inc.php';

$companyName = "Student Beheer Systeem";

function strip_bad_chars($input)
{
    $output = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $input);
    return $output;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
</head>
<body id="final-example">

    <!-------     LOGIN / LOGOUT FORM               --------->

    <?php
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['idUsers'])) {
        echo '<img id="status" src="">';
    } else {
        echo '<img id="status" src="">';
    }
    ?>
    <div id="login">

        <?php
        $imgName = isset($_SESSION['imgUsers']) ? $_SESSION['imgUsers'] : "default.png";
        if (isset($_SESSION['idUsers'])) {
            echo '
                    </div>
                    <div id="philosophy">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="split Left">
                                <img class="logo" style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 20%; width: 40%; align-items: center; position: absolute; background-size: 80px;" src="https://www.summacollege.nl/images/default-source/default-album/logo.png?sfvrsn=17f34f85_6">
                                <div class="centered">
                                    <div class="UnderForm">
                                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <img id="userDp" src=./uploads/' . $imgName . '>
                        <h3>' . strtoupper($_SESSION['f_name']) . ' ' . strtoupper($_SESSION['l_name']) . '</h3>
                        <a href="personal-profile.php" class="button login">Profiel</a>  
                        <a href="edit-personal-profile.php" class="button login">Bewerk Profiel</a>
                        <a href="search-student.php" class="button login">Zoek student</a>
                        <a href="includes/logout.inc.php" class="button login">Uitloggen</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="split Right">
                                <div class="Background-Right">
                                    <img id="splash" class="splash" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3186386/pexels-photo-3186386.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-stanley-morales-3186386.jpg&fm=jpg">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
        } else {
            if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
                if ($_GET['error'] == 'emptyfields') {
                    echo '<p class="closed">*please fill in all the fields</p>';
                } else if ($_GET['error'] == 'nouser') {
                    echo '<p class="closed">*username does not exist</p>';
                } else if ($_GET['error'] == 'wrongpwd') {
                    echo '<p class="closed">*wrong password</p>';
                } else if ($_GET['error'] == 'sqlerror') {
                    echo '<p class="closed">*website error. contact admint to have it fixed [SQL ERROR]</p>';
                }
            }

            echo '
                <div id="philosophy">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="split Left">
                        <img class="logo" style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 20%; width: 40%; align-items: center; position: absolute; background-size: 80px;" src="https://www.summacollege.nl/images/default-source/default-album/logo.png?sfvrsn=17f34f85_6">
                        <div class="centered">
                            <div class="UnderForm">
                                <form method="post" action="includes/login.inc.php" id="login-form">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username..."><br><br>
                                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password..."><br><br>
                                    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" class="button next login" style="background: #24126E" name="login-submit" value="Login">
                </form>
                <a href="signup.php" class="button previous">Signup</a>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox" name="Checkbox" unchecked>
                                <label for="checkbox" id="Checkbox">Remember me</label>
                                <p>____________________________________________________of____________________________________________________</p>
                                <button style="background: #D70096">Contact Support</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="split Right">
                        <div class="Background-Right">
        
                            <img id="splash" class="splash" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3186386/pexels-photo-3186386.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-stanley-morales-3186386.jpg&fm=jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
        }
        ?>

    </div>

    <!-------     LOGIN / LOGOUT FORM END           --------->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
```

Comment: This is not the way sessions work. It's only showing the last one because you are overwriting the values on each loop. You need to do the query again on the profile page to get the values, or pass them over the URL. There is no need to use session variables for that at all.

Comment: `<?php  session_start(); ?>` shouldn't be in the `head` of HTML, it should be one of the first things on the page, before output. Why have ` if (isset($_SESSION['idUsers'])) {` and do the same thing for both? Your `'%$key%'` also is open to SQL injections. Always parameterize queries with input.